# How to use Android BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-bitmap

This method decodes Bitmaps without producing `OutOfMemory` exception:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
{
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;
    options.inPurgeable = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

But the fields `inInputShareable` and `inPurgeable` are deprecated in sdk=21.

How do I change the above method to use `BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap`?

Will it run correctly on pre-21 devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I change the above method to use BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap?

Set `options.inBitmap` to an existing `Bitmap` object that you would like to reuse as the destination for the decoding.

> Will it run correctly on pre-21 devices?

That will depend entirely on what you supply as the `Bitmap` and how you define "correctly":

- On API Level 19+, the `Bitmap` needs to be the same size or larger than the `Bitmap` that you are trying to decode. Otherwise, the `Bitmap` will be ignored and you will get a new `Bitmap`.
- On older devices, the `Bitmap` needs to be the same size (resolution) as the `Bitmap` that you are trying to decode. Otherwise, the `Bitmap` will be ignored and you will get a new `Bitmap`.